# Why does my TOC appears itself below the title of "table of contents"?

Tags: table-of-contents

I can´t understand why does Table of content name appears twice in my output document, I mean one little version of it below the title I really want.
I'm using sharelatex, and Latex as compiler because using pdftex doesnt renders out the logo of my university in `.eps` format in my `titlepage.tex` file.

Here goes the top part of the code:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=4cm,headheight=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{  \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{  \leftmark}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1in,bottom=.6in,top=.8in}
\begin{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\input{./titlepage.tex}
\end{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\restoregeometry
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Página}\par}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introducción}
```

---

[image]

As you can see "Índice" (Table of contents in spanish when using babel) appears two times.

Comment: use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` or delete it if not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to prevent the inclusion of the ToC entry in ToC itself. The default behaviour of this package is to do so.

About the minor issue with the `.eps` file: Try to use `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`, without `dvips` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=4cm,headheight=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{  \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{  \leftmark}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1in,bottom=.6in,top=.8in}
\begin{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble} 
%\input{./titlepage.tex}
\end{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\restoregeometry
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Página}\par}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introducción}

\end{document}
```

[image]